# JQuery - change DIV html with Select Menu value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, function

I have a JQuery `SelectMenu` with the values set as php include statements.

I want those values to be ascribed to my `div`.

I've looked at different resources and can't figure out the syntax.  Here's the code that I wrote

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var display = $( "#display" );

        $( "#selector" ).selectmenu({
          change: function( event, data ) {
            display.html(data.item.value);
            });
          }
         });
    </script>

    <div>
        <select name="selector" id="selector">
            <option value="<?php include 'one.html';?>">One</option>
            <option value="<?php include 'two.html';?>">Two</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <div id="display"> Old Text </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

*** Solution ***

```
HTML:

<div>
    <select name="selector" id="selector">
        <option value="blood/blood.html">One</option>
        <option value="grace/grace.html">Two</option>
    </select>
    <div id="display"> Old Text </div>
</div>

* replaced php includes with html file

JS / Jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function() {
        var work = $( "#display" );
        $( "#selector" ).change(function( event ) {
            work.load($(this).val());
        });
    });
});

* Changed html to load
```

Comment: I got rid of your n00b statement.  Don't degrade yourself like that.  We're here to help.  I've also fixed a couple of trouble spots with your grammar.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I added the solution in the question. Still learning stackoverflow etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to do what you need to do with only jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var work = $( "#display" );
    $( "#selector" ).change(function( event ) {
        work.html($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Your js fiddle was not working because you didn't include jquery, or jqueryui which is needed if you want to use the selectmenu function. Also you had an issue with your parenthesis not nested correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this. I believe your corrections made the function perform the task i wanted. However, i'm thinking there may be an flaw with the concept of using include statements like this. I am now getting internal server error message. I'm going to try using a variable as was suggested by @Shay. Not enough cred to up-vote, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use a variable there?

I hope you are passing merely a value in the end and not some HTML/php codes, if you are then it should still work just fine, although it is not a good practice I believe to include a file inside a value attribute. :)

Comment: My original build used multiple divs with include statements. I just set the css to display:none on load and changed it with jquery buttons. It seems like this was making too many requests upfront, so i'm trying to look at different ideas. Each html file has an mp3 at several MB. Any thoughts as to why it's a bad idea to include a file inside a value attribute?

Comment: A value attribute should consist of a simple value, usually a string or a number.
Include function is serving a different purpose, it extracts all contents of a file and includes them into a page, such as a block of HTML code, or a block of php code/functions.
If it is an mp3 you seek to put as value, you should use the name of the mp3 file as a **string** inside that value, and then extract that string value using jQuery/php, and using it as a variable wherever you need it. :)